# DateTime add 1 day

Tags: php, datetime, for-loop

My Form has 2 fields - Time_from and Time_to

Now i need to add an entry in my database for each day (If theres is a difference between those days)
ex. Time_from = 2013-08-26 08:00:00 and Time_to = 2013-08-28 16:00:00
So in my database i should get 3 entries

```
Time_from = 2013-08-26 08:00:00 and Time_to = 2013-08-26 16:00:00
Time_from = 2013-08-27 08:00:00 and Time_to = 2013-08-27 16:00:00
Time_from = 2013-08-28 08:00:00 and Time_to = 2013-08-28 16:00:00
```

So for that purpose i have made a method, where i first find the difference between those 2 dates and then i'm using a for loop that will run as many days in difference those 2 dates have, and at the end im just adding 1 day.

```
public function createOffer($offer)
{
$time_from = new DateTime($offer->time_from);
$time_to = new DateTime($offer->time_to);
$interval = $time_from->diff($time_to);

for ($counter = 0; $counter <= $interval->d; $counter++) {
    $offer->time_from = $time_from->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $offer_time_to = new DateTime($time_from->format('Y-m-d'));
    $offer_time_to->setTime($time_to->format('H'), $time_to->format('i')
        , $time_to->format('s'));
    $offer->time_to = $offer_time_to->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if ($offer->validate()) {
    $offer->save();
    }

    date_modify($time_from, '+1 day');
    }
}
```

For some reason, the code doesn't work.

When i remove the date_modify field only the first day will be saved in my database (Guess the for loop is only running once then)

But with the date_modify in my code, only the last day is saved in the database.

Comment: $interval->d there is no "days" difference, only hours, in the times given so the loop will only run once

Comment: So the difference between days is only shown i hours?

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3r1-6hc are you sure you dont want $interval->h rather than interval->d

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you can use Add function of Datatime object

here i am giving you one example to add one 1 in your post date like

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2000-01-02
```

Hope it will sure help you to solve your issue.

Comment: I still get the same result, only the last day is saved in the database.

Comment: please trace date before you pass in new DateTime('your date'); and your function should be return every time new date means 3 times you need to call or return value from function.

Comment: You solution seem to work .. Apparently there is an Jquery problem, that is responsible for the bug ..

Answer (score 9):

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-01-17');
$date->modify('+1 day');

echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-01-18
```

You can do it too:

```
$dateTo = new \DateTime('1980-12-07 +1 day');
echo $dateTo->format('Y-m-d'); // 1980-12-08
```